# What is the runtime type of my union function variable? Is it returning a Promise or an Observable?

Tags: typescript

I have this abstract variable in my class:

```
abstract save(): Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>;
```

I have a function that runs this `save` function that the derived class implemented. How can I check if it is a promise or an observable?

```
executeSave(): void {
  if (///// is this a promise??? /////) {
    (<Promise<boolean>>this.save()).then(isSaved => { ... });
  } else {
    (<Observable<boolean>>this.save()).subscribe(isSaved => { ... });
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't check *before* you've called it. Check the *methods* the result has?

Comment: `isSaved() => {}` isn't valid syntax...

Comment: you're correct, my bad. fixing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be achieved using the handy `instanceof` operator. This also gives you the benefit that the type of your variable (in your case `toSave`) will be automatically inferred to the type of the right-hand side of your `instanceof` operation inside the if-block. So you won't need to typecast.

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

executeSave(): void {
    const toSave = this.save();
    if (toSave instanceof Observable) { 
        // Since you used "instanceof" here, typescript knows that "toSave" is of type "Observable" inside this if
        toSave.subscribe(isSaved => { /* omitted */ });
    } else if (toSave instanceof Promise) { // else would be enough, since there are only two possible types for "toSave"
        // Same goes for the Promise
        toSave.then(isSaved => { /* omitted */ });
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As stated in comments, second typecheck is not needed. I adjusted the comment in code accordingly.

Comment: actually, if the return type is only 2 options, and you rule one out, TS is smart enough to infer that it must be the other type, so the secondary check isn't needed.

Comment: `else { toSave.then(isSaved => { /* omitted */ }); }` is working. no need to typecast

Comment: up-voted you both. your answers are kind of the same. I would say that the key point of both answers is that I need to execute the `save` function first, and than check its type. I will mark this as correct answer just because it's not depending or rxjs function and it is just javascript. 10x to you both pascal and @bryan60.

Comment: @benshabatnoam Thank you very much. I adjusted the example accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

easiest way is to use rxjs inbuilt isObservable test:

```
import { isObservable } from "rxjs";

executeSave(): void {
  const toSave = this.save();
  if (isObservable(toSave)) { // checks if observable
    toSave.subscribe(isSaved => { ... });
  } else { // only 2 options so this is a promise
    toSave.then(isSaved => { ... });
  }
}
```

also don't need the forced typings anymore

Comment: up-voted you both. your answers are kind of the same. I would say that the key point of both answers is that I need to execute the `save` function first, and than check its type. I will mark pascalpuetz's answer as correct answer just because it's not depending or rxjs function and it is just javascript. 10x to you both pascal and @bryan60.

Comment: Whichever is your pref, but FYI the RxJS function uses instanceof under the hood but also adds what’s known as a typeguard and has some secondary checks that I’m assuming are important in some cases though I honestly don’t know them https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/src/internal/util/isObservable.ts